# Sockets in python

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.6

im writting an app using python and sockets, here is piece of the server code:

```
while True:
  c = random.choice(temp_deck)
  temp_deck.remove(c)

  if hakem == p1:
      p1.send(pickle.dumps(('{} for {}'.format(c,'you'),False)))
      p2.send(pickle.dumps(('{} for {}'.format(c,'other'),False)))
  else:
      p1.send(pickle.dumps(('{} for {}'.format(c,'other'),False)))
      p2.send(pickle.dumps(('{} for {}'.format(c,'you'),False)))

  if c in ['A♠','A♣','A♦','A♥']:
      if hakem == p1:
          p1.send(pickle.dumps(('You are Hakem!',False)))
          p2.send(pickle.dumps(('Other Player is Hakem!',False)))
          break
      else:
          p1.send(pickle.dumps(('Other Player is Hakem!',False)))
          p2.send(pickle.dumps(('You are Hakem!',False)))
          break
  if hakem == p1:
      hakem = p2
      other = p1
  else:
      hakem = p1
      other = p2
```

this needs two clients to connect, everything is fine except clients don't receive full data:
for example one gets:

3♠ for other

2♠ for you

10♣ for other

10♦ for you

A♣ for other

the other gets:

2♠ for you

10♣ for other

10♦ for you

A♣ for other

what should i do?

client code:

```
import socket
import pickle

s = socket.socket()

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 12345

s.connect((host, port))

while True:
    o = pickle.loads(s.recv(1024))
    print(o[0])
    if o[1] == True:
        s.send(pickle.dumps(input(">")))
s.close
```

Comment: Maybe you need to `flush` the socket after sending? Without seeing the full code and ideally a minimal example, it's hard to tell.

Comment: [TCP sockets are byte streams, not message streams](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html) This is probably too much to explain in a SO answer. I tried multiple times in years long past, which i why I wrote that blog post.

Comment: The tl;dr is that when you `send` on on side and `recv` on the other, there's no guarantee that the `recv` gets an entire `send`. It could get half a `send`, or two and a half `send`s. At least you've chosen a self-delimiting protocol, pickle, which takes care of the other problem people usually run into. And actually, maybe that's enough to make this one answerable. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Actually, looking at your output, that may not be the problem. If not, it _will_ be a problem once you try to run this over the internet, but you might have a different problem blocking you before you even get to that point, in which case my answer isn't relevant to your question (although you should still read it).

Comment: Can we see the relevant client code?

Comment: So should i delete this post,?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that TCP sockets are byte streams, not message streams. When you `send` some data and the client does a `recv`, there's no guarantee that it will receive everything you sent. It may get half the message. It may get multiple messages at once.

I've explained this at some length in [a blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/sockets-are-byte-streams-not-message.html)—but fortunately, you're actually only hitting half the problem, and it's ultimately the simpler half. You've chosen to use a stream of `pickle` messages as your protocol, and `pickle` is a self-delimiting (aka framed) protocol.

`pickle.load` can load pickle after pickle out of anything with a file-like interface. And if your client and server are built around blocking I/O (e.g., using a thread for each direction on the socket), you can simulate `read` by doing blocking `recv` calls and appending them onto a buffer until you have enough bytes to satisfy the `read`.

And, even better, you don't have to do that yourself, because that's exactly what the builtin [`socket.makefile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.makefile) does. I haven't done any more than a quick test with this, so I won't promise it's bulletproof, but…

On the client side, you probably have something like this:

```
sock.connect(...)
# more stuff

# in a loop somewhere
    buf = sock.recv(16384)
    msg = pickle.loads(buf)

# later
sock.close()
```

Change it to this:

```
sock.connect(...)
rfile = socket.makefile('rb')
# more stuff

# in a loop somewhere
    msg = pickle.load(rfile)

# later
rfile.close()
sock.close()
```

And it just works.

Again, you should test this. And you should read either my blog post, or a more complete primer on sockets programming and TCP, to understand what's going on. And really, you're probably better off designing your app around a higher-level framework (`asyncio` is really cool, especially with the syntactic support in Python 3.5+, or I think Twisted already has a pickle protocol class pre-written for you…). But this may be enough to get you started.